# Updating state in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm using the AASM gem to manage states on one of my models. Right now, I'm using a form_for in a javascript popup to change the state, but it's not working:

```
<h2>Set the state:</h2>
<%= form_for(@tracker) do |f| %>
  <% if @tracker.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>Uh-oh. We've got some problems</h2>
      <% @tracker.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <%= msg %><br />
      <% end %>

    </div>
  <% end %>

This tracker is currently: <%= @tracker.state %><br />

<%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(Tracker::STATEDESCRIPTIONS.map { |event| [event.to_s.humanize, event]}) %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

What I'd really like to do, though, is contain the form all in a single button, but I'm not sure what to use for that? `button_to`?

Comment: What exactly is not working? The combo is not showing the possible states correctly? Or the controller does not save the state? If so, please provide the controller source as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `f.select` instead of `select_tag`. That way, the resulting `select` HTML tag will be associated with the `form_for(@tracker)`, and the chosen state will be correctly mapped to `@tracker` in the controller action in question.